# Java getCanvasImage and paintComponent draws out of sync

Tags: java, canvas, synchronization, paintcomponent

**Objective:**
I'm trying to draw bounding boxes around NPCs from a game client. I need to save the screenshot to a folder and save the box coordinates to a text file.

**Problem:**
When I rotate the camera, the boxes drawn on the canvas no longer align with the NPCs. It looks like the NPC coordinates lag behind the screenshot that is being draw on. Some of the screenshots also appear to be half previous frame and half new frame. I assume this may be related to multiple images being sent to save before the first one completes. Another thing to note is that the boxes don't finish drawing before the next frame appears on the canvas.

How can I force the screenshots to sync with the box coordinates? Is there some way I can get the game data and screenshot at the same time and then force the client to stop drawing until the task is complete?

This is the first time I've ever worked with Java (The data this script collects is intended for use with a Python project I'm working on) so please simplify answers as much as possible.

*Update:*
After messing around with things, it appears that the screen tearing may be the main issue. The delay looks like it's caused by the screen tear. The boxes are being drawn at the correct position on the parts of the screen that didn't get updated before they were saved.

https://media.giphy.com/media/39yEawmLBT4zKpPoz3/giphy.gif

[image: Misaligned]

[image: Misaligned]

[image: Misaligned]

Performing at its worst:

[image: Misaligned]

Tearing:

[image: Tearing]

```
public class Pair {
   public String key;
   public Rectangle value;

   public Pair(String key, Rectangle value) {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   }
}

public class MyPaint extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9091790544960515120L;
    private BufferedImage paintImage = getClient().getCanvasImage();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(paintImage, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public void updatePaint(){
        synchronized (this) {
            Graphics g = paintImage.createGraphics();

            List<NPC> rsNpcs = new NPCs(getClient()).all()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(i -> i.getName().equals(npcName)
                             &&  i.isOnScreen() == true
                             &&  inTile(i.getTile()) == false)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            //Classifying the NPC in the box for the text file.
            for (NPC rsNpc : rsNpcs) {
                Rectangle bbox = rsNpc.getBoundingBox(); 
                g.drawRect(bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height);

                if (rsNpc.isInCombat() == true) {
                    Pair rsNpcPair = new Pair("CombatChicken", bbox);
                    onScreenRsNpcs.add(rsNpcPair);
                } else {
                    Pair rsNpcPair = new Pair("RegularChicken", bbox);
                    onScreenRsNpcs.add(rsNpcPair);
                }
            }

            //This bit is to save the boxes to a text file:
            for (Pair rsNpc : onScreenRsNpcs) {
                String data = (String.valueOf(rsNpc.value) + "Class Name: " + rsNpc.key + " Image Name: " + String.valueOf(count));
                globalData.add(data);
            }

            g.dispose();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void save() throws IOException{
            ImageIO.write(paintImage, "PNG", new File(String.format("%s/%s.jpg", getManifest().name(), count)));
            count = count + 1;
    }

    public void load() throws IOException {
        paintImage = ImageIO.read(new File(String.format("%s/%s.jpg", getManifest().name(), count)));
        repaint();
    }
}


//...


private MyPaint paint;


public void onStart() {
    paint = new MyPaint();
}


//...


@Override
public int onLoop() {   
    try {
        paint.updatePaint();
        paint.save();
        paint.load();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you're drawing the image on a background thread, then you need to put `synchronized(this) {...}` around `g.drawImage(paintImage, 0, 0, null);` for correctness, but I don't think that will fix everything.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think we can help much without knowing a lot more about what you're doing and seeing more of your code. (For example, what does `rsNpc.getBoundingBox()` return? What are `getClient()`, `getCanvasImage()`, etc., etc.? It looks like you're using some kind of a Runescape API or something? There's just too much we don't know.) Take some time to read through the help article on the [mcve] and do your best to recreate one here for this problem.

Comment: I'm using a RuneScape botting API. The point of this script is to collect training images for a convolutional neural network. I really wanted to work with my own dataset and one I have a lot of control over while trying to educate myself on the subject. RuneScape has a lot of botting clients out there so I figured this would be a good way to do it. `rsNpc.getBoundingBox()` gets the coordinates of the NPC on screen. It returns a Rectangle object comprised of 4 integers: x, y, width, height. `getClient().getCanvasImage()` gets the canvas for the client instance and returns a buffered image.